# Closing FTDI Comm port with CloseHandle() takes a lot of time

Tags: c++, c, winapi, serial-port, ftdi

I'm working in a C/C++ program that communicates with a RS232 device.
The port is opened using CreateFile()

```
hComm = CreateFile(DevPath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
```

Then, the port is Setup using SetupComm(), SetCommState() and SetCommTimeouts() with no hardware control and a baudrate of 115200 baud and timeouts as shown here:

```
    cTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
    cTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
    cTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    cTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 40;
    cTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
```

The port is closed using CloseHandle()

```
CloseHandle(hComm);
```

This is not a real-time system but has to be very fast, and after noticing some delays I've measured that instruction CloseHandle() takes always more than 100ms to run, which is a huge amount of time, taking into account that opening and configuring the port takes only 20ms.

Test conditions are as follows:

- There isn't any anti-virus or firewall in the test machine (off-line).
- I'm using Visual Studio on an brand-new Intel-based Core-i5 computer, running in Windows 10.
- FTDI USB device (Virtual CommPort)
- There is no data pending to be read or written (or it shouldn't).

I've tried to compile a similar program in Linux and the Close time reduces to **25ms**.
I've also tried to use a physical RS232 connection and the close times turns to be **1ms**, so I presume this comes from the FTDI driver.

Does anyone have any clue on what could be happening. Am I missing anything?
Did anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: How many bytes do you send or receive on this port before closing it? Is it possible that buffered bytes need to be handled?

Comment: Why don't you try this? [bmo/mttty](https://github.com/bmo/mttty)

Comment: I can not determine the cause of the problem, perhaps the port needs to handle handles or data caching. And although you do not have a firewall or anti-virus software installed, you may be running MSE or Windows Defender.

Comment: What I have experienced is that the async request being published (WaitCommEvent/ReadFile/WriteFile) does not complete. Why not issue a SetCommMask with a different mask value or a PurgeComm that cancels everything before CloseHandle?
However, due to a bug in the device driver, the system sometimes hung up when the above measures were taken.

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52926868/non-overlapped-serial-port-hangs-at-closehandle ?

Comment: @busybee Depends on the session I could send a few bytes or thousands of kilobytes. But that's not the issue. I'm pretty sure that buffers are empty before closing, in fact I check them and purge them, just in case.

Comment: @kunif Thanks for the info. I'm already purging the port, but you might be right. I was checking the link passed by Cristian B. and I will try to set the Mask and force the RTS, CTS... lines just in case this makes any difference (despite I'm not using them).

Comment: I've tested everything: CancelIo(), PurgeComm(), SetCommTimeouts(), SetCommState(), SetCommMask(), etc. But does not make any difference.
By the way, I've just received a response from FTDI and they aknowkledge the delay, despite they don't consider this is an issue, giving the ball to Microsoft and their driver/port handling. I doubt this is the cause, since it works perfect while using a physical RS232 connection. They might have something wrong in their driver...